# Can you check object's state using sleuth?

Tags: spring, logging, trace, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I am trying to figure out if I can trace some objects fields using **sleuth**.
I am currently lost in Zipkin's and Sleuth's docs. Does anybody do this?
Can we add an object to span and view its details in logs?

Answer (score 1):

You can only do that just before the span gets reported. You can't check its details at runtime.